# Listview viewholder and image

Tags: android, image, listview, lag

Everybody. I've tried to use a `viewholder adapter`, but I couldn't understand and my app stopped working. I need some help. I read some blogs that explained this. No success.

This is my code below and I just want how to modify this using a `viewholder adapter` or something else to my listview works fine with no lag. I'm more visua and if someone gives an example using my code, I'll appreciate for this. P.S: My Listview has more than 100 items, but I just reduced here to clarify and facilitate the view of my code.

```
public class Listagem extends Activity {

    EditText edittext;
    ListView listview;

    String[] text;  
    String[] text2;

    int[] image = {
        R.drawable.wolf;
        R.drawable.cat;
    };

    int textlength = 0;
    ArrayList<String> text_sort = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> text2_sort = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Integer> image_sort = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        text =  getResources().getStringArray(R.array.text);
        text2 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.text2);

        edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);

        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { 

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                    if ("Howl".equals(text[position])) {
                        MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(Listagem.this, R.raw.howl);
                        player.start();
                    }

                    if ("Meow".equals(text[position])) {
                        MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(Listagem.this, R.raw.meow);
                        player.start();
                    }
                }          
        });

        listview.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(text, text2, image));
        edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                textlength = edittext.getText().length();
                text_sort.clear();
                text2_sort.clear();
                image_sort.clear();

                for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
                    if (textlength <= text[i].length()) {
                        if (edittext.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase((String) text[i].subSequence(0, textlength))) {
                            text_sort.add(text[i]);
                            text2_sort.add(text2[i]);
                            image_sort.add(image[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }


                listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                        if ("Howl".equals(text_sort.get(position))) {
                            MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(Listagem.this, R.raw.howl);
                            player.start();
                        }

                        if ("Meow".equals(text_sort.get(position))) {
                            MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(Listagem.this, R.raw.meow);
                            player.start();
                        }
                    }
                });
                listview.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(text_sort, text2_sort, image_sort));
            }
        });
    }


    class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        String[] data_text;
        String[] data_text2;
        int[] data_image;

        MyCustomAdapter() {

        }

        MyCustomAdapter(String[] text, String[] text2, int[] image) {
            data_text = text;
            data_text2 = text2;
            data_image = image;
        }

        MyCustomAdapter(ArrayList<String> text, ArrayList<String> text2, ArrayList<Integer> image) {
            data_text = new String[text.size()];
            data_text2 = new String[text2.size()];
            data_image = new int[image.size()];

            for(int i=0;i<text.size();i++) {
                data_text[i] = text.get(i);
                data_text2[i] = text2.get(i);
                data_image[i] = image.get(i);
            }
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return data_text.length;
        }

        public String getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View row;

            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, parent, false);

            listview.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            listview.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
            listview.setScrollingCacheEnabled(false);

            TextView textview = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
            TextView textview2 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.TextView02);

            Typeface font1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "arial.ttf");  
            textview2.setTypeface(font1);
            ImageView imageview = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);

            textview.setText(data_text[position]);
            textview2.setText(data_text2[position]);
            imageview.setImageResource(data_image[position]);

            return row;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If your app stopped working you should *always* post your logcat errors.

Comment: All right, this code is fine, but I don't know how to "convert" this ou use a viewholder that combines with this....

Comment: 2 things - Please don't post a very long code, and if you do - format it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `getView()` method is wrong. It doesn't recycle views. That is the first problem you have to fix. Then if you want to improve the performance of the method by using the ViewHolder design pattern have a look to this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder)

And please, follow the advises given to you in the above comments.